# Debian 9 strange wi fi behaviour

Tags: debian, wifi

I've installed Debian stretch on macbook air

had problems with the non-free wifi broadcom [was't so difficult on jessie]
i managed to get it working

when i turn machine off and switch on again the wifi does not connect automatically.

in command line after:

```
su
modprobe -r brcmsmac ; modprobe brcmsmac
```

and it connects.

what should i be doing to make the machine connect normally?

Also does this error have any relevance to the question?

```
root@sherab-mac:/home/sherab# modprobe wl

modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem following the tutorial from [Debians](https://wiki.debian.org/fr/wl) website, it turned out that replacing :

```
# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

With the output from `echo $(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')` (In my case `"amd64"`) fixed the problem.